# Running a while loop until specific input received, but rerunning if nothing received c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

I'm trying to run a while loop until enter is pressed on terminal, but as far as I can tell the loop stops at cin.get() until something is received. Is there a way to make the input from the terminal optional and rerun the while loop?
Here is the loop from the code, if I take out the cin.get() parts it works well, I just can't stop it.

```
        while (true) {

        // In each iteration of our main loop, we run the Myo event loop for a set number of milliseconds.
        hub.run(1);

        // Extract first timestamp from Myo (string casted as a number)
        if (tstart == 0){
            stringstream myStream(collector.stampTime);
            myStream >> tstart;
        }

        // Extracting samples from DataCollector
        std::array<float, 3> acceData = collector.acceSamples;
        std::array<float, 3> gyroData = collector.gyroSamples;
        std::array<float, 3> oriData = collector.oriSamples;
        std::array<int8_t, 8> emgData = collector.emgSamples;

        for (int i = 0; i < emgData.size(); i++){

            if (i < 3) {
                // Accelerometer samples
                acce[i] = acceData[i];
                pAcce[i] = acce[i];

                // Gyroscope samples
                gyro[i] = gyroData[i];
                pGyro[i] = gyro[i];

                // Orientation samples
                ori[i] = oriData[i];
                pOri[i] = ori[i];
            }

            // EMG samples
            emg[i] = emgData[i];
            pEMG[i] = emg[i];
        }

        /*
        * Plot the result
        */
        engPutVariable(ep, "Acce", Acce);
        engPutVariable(ep, "Gyro", Gyro);
        engPutVariable(ep, "Ori", Ori);
        engPutVariable(ep, "EMG", EMG);
        engEvalString(ep,"EMG_gather");

        // Extract timestamps from Myo (string casted as a number) and compute elapsed time
        stringstream myStream(collector.stampTime);
        myStream >> tend;
        elapsedTime = (tend - tstart)/1000000;

        // Keep track of how many runs Myo has performed
        x++;
        if (x % 30 == 0){
            std::cout << x << endl;
        }


        if (cin.get() == '\n')
            break;
        else if (cin.get() == '')
            continue;
    }
```

Comment: This cannot  be  done in standard c++, you need platform - specific API.

Comment: Eugene, that's not true. At leas you can have separate thread that reads data in a blocking way and uses condition variable to notify worker thread. But there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how complicated you want the input to be, but based on what you've posted, you could also 
use the [`std::signal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal) function like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

namespace {
    volatile std::sig_atomic_t m_stop;
}

static void app_msg_pump(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGINT || sig == SIGTERM) {
        m_stop = sig;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    m_stop = 0;
    std::signal(SIGINT, &app_msg_pump);  // catch signal interrupt request
    std::signal(SIGTERM, &app_msg_pump); // catch signal terminate request
    while (m_stop == 0) {
        // your loop code here
    }
    std::cout << "Stopping.." << std::endl;
    // your clean up code here
    return 0;
}
```

This will run until the user presses `CTRL+C` (the usual console signal interrupt key handler), you can modify the above code to ignore the key press as well and just handle the fact that a user requested the interrupt.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Is `std::cout <<` signal-safe? I'm having my doubts. Have had my programs stuck in a `malloc` deadlock one too many times to find out, now I just set a `volatile std::sig_atomic_t` and return.

Comment: good catch @TheVee .. undefined behavior works the way you expect it sometimes on some platforms, but is still undefined :) `std::cout` is not so much "signal-safe", it's just undefined to call any standard library function from a user installed signal handler in the manner I originally had posted.